# Как объединить запрос?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Имеется такой запрос:

```
SELECT tel_id, sum(money) FROM `accounts` WHERE date >= CURDATE() AND type = 1 AND status = 1 GROUP BY tel_id
```

И такой:

```
SELECT tel_id, sum(money) FROM `accounts` WHERE date >= CURDATE() AND type IN (2,3,4) AND status = 1 GROUP BY tel_id
```

Как объединить данные запросы, чтобы в результате получилось так:

### | tel_id | sum1 | sum2 |

Comment: для обьединения столбцов используется **join**, но для вашего случая лучше `sum(case when условие then money end)` два раза с разными условиями

Comment: А групировка точно разная? почему вы выбираете  tel_id поле а групируете по terminal_id? так нельзя. Конечно c помощью **union** можно всё обьеденить, но всётаки тут ошибка

Comment: @nick_n_a там ошибка, tel_id должно быть. Можно пример с case when? Как это должно выглядеть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может создать одельно статью как обьединять запросы. Хочу показать несколько способов обьеденить запросы по столбцам (чуть поправив - можно по-строкам). 
Способ 1. **join**

```
SELECT t1.tel_id , sum(t2.money) sum1, sum(t3.money) from `accounts` t1
left join `accounts` t2 on t1.tel_id = t2.tel_id and date >= CURDATE() AND type = 1 AND status = 1 
left join `accounts` t3 on t1.tel_id = t3.tel_id and date >= CURDATE() AND type IN (2,3,4) AND status = 1 
GROUP BY t1.tel_id
```

Способ 2 **union**  (для понимания как обьеденить через union)

```
select  tel_id, sum(sum1) sum1,  sum(sum2) sum2 from (
  SELECT tel_id,  sum(money) sum1, null sum2 FROM `accounts` WHERE date >= CURDATE() AND type = 1 AND status = 1 GROUP BY tel_id
  union SELECT tel_id, null  , sum(money) FROM `accounts` WHERE date >= CURDATE() AND type IN (2,3,4) AND status = 1 GROUP BY tel_id
) t group by  tel_id
```

Способ 3 UPD:
надо не забывать, что если есть выражение типа `select * from table1 where id=1 union  select * from table1 where id=2` то union  вам не нужен, т.к. проще переписать через **or** так

```
select * from table1 where (id = 1 /*условие1*/) or (id=2 /*условие2*/)
```

и тогда переходим дальше, добавив в выборку выше некоторые изменения получим способ 3 ниже, при этом выражение c **or** "сокращается"

Способ 3 (лучший для даного случая) **case** как пример того когда не нужно вообще обьединять запросы как насмешка над двумя предыдущими

```
 SELECT t1.tel_id , 
   sum(case when date >= CURDATE() AND type = 1 AND status = 1 then money end) sum1,
   sum(case when date >= CURDATE() AND type IN (2,3,4) AND status = 1  then money end) sum2  from   `accounts` 
 /*where условие1 or условие2 которые сократились */
 group by  tel_id
```

Способ 4, вложеный *select* в аргументы, нужен для разнородных запросов, похож на способ 1

```
select tel_id,
     (select sum(t2.money) from `accounts` t2  where t1.tel_id = t2.tel_id and date >= CURDATE() AND type = 1 AND status = 1  ) sum1,
     (select sum(t3.money) from `accounts` t3  where t1.tel_id = t3.tel_id and date >= CURDATE() AND type IN (2,3,4) AND status = 1) sum2
from `accounts` t1  group by tel_id
```

Посмотрел посмотрел на свои запросы свежим взглядом, и скажу, что их можно упростить, например в 3-ем запросе и не только, вынести status=1 за where основного запроса, но это уже проще. Цель показать пути решения. Пробуйте - получится.

Comment: Третий кажется наиболее оптимальным. только в where лучше указать все условия: `date >= CURDATE() AND type in(1,2,3,4)  AND status = 1` что бы запрос не пытался даже рассматривать лишние записи. (вдруг там еще 10к разных type). И в списке выборки тогда достаточно будет проверить на type=1 и type!=1. Ну и для упрощения записи в MySQL есть замечательная функция `sum( if(type=1,  money, 0) )`, хотя и не совместимая с другими диалектами SQL