# Упрощение и объединение двух SQL запросов.

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте, есть два SQL запроса:

```
SELECT s.date , s.group_id , s.duration, g.status_id, u.name
  FROM schedule s
  INNER JOIN user u ON s.user_id = u.id AND s.user_id = 13
  INNER JOIN `group` g ON s.group_id = g.id  AND  g.status_id = 3
  INNER JOIN group_history gh ON s.group_id = gh.group_id AND gh.status_id = 3 
  AND gh.end_date IS NULL
  WHERE s.date >= '2018-03-23 00:00:00'
  AND s.date <= gh.start_date;
SELECT s.date , s.group_id , s.duration, g.status_id , u.name 
  FROM schedule s
  INNER JOIN user u ON s.user_id = u.id AND s.user_id = 13
  INNER JOIN `group` g ON s.group_id = g.id  AND g.status_id = 2
  WHERE s.date >= '2018-03-23 00:00:00'
  AND s.date <= '2018-03-31 23:59:59';
```

Вывод таблиц:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли будет объединить их в одну таблицу, ведь поля одинаковые?

Comment: дак напишите UNION и попробуйте

Comment: @teran когда не до конца изучил SQL. 
Спасибо. :DD 
Оформи ответ, зачту.

Comment: Почитайте это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546912/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81/546930#546930 способ 2 и 3

Comment: union тут не лучший (по быстродействию) способ, зато... самый простой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оператор `UNION` используется для объединения двух или более результурующих наборов.

- Каждый результирующий набор в `UNION` должен иметь одинаковое
  количество столбцов.
- Столбцы должны иметь похожие типы данных.

Оператор `UNION` **по умолчанию выбирает уникальные значения**. Чтобы разрешить повторяющиеся значения, используйте `UNION ALL`.

Подробнее [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql).